# Sub-sequence numbers in a string

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm getting the longest consecutive increasing numbers in an array with 10 items

```
int list[] = {2,3,8,9,10,11,12,2,6,8};
int start_pos = 0;
int lenght=0; // lenght of the sub-~consetuve
for (int a =0; a <=9; a++ )
{

    if ((list[a]+1) == (list[a+1])) {
        // continue just the string;
        lenght++;
    } else {
        start_pos = a;
    }
}
cout << lenght  << " and start in " << start_pos;
getchar();
```

but it not working, it should return in length & start_pos ( 3 and lenght 4 ) because longest increasing is from 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 but it not working.

Comment: Show us some code Bill :)

Comment: I think one of your problems might be overflow.  There's a maximum size to integers in C++, and once it's exceeded, it reverts to -(that maximum size).

Comment: That's not a longest *subsequence*, it's a longest *consecutive run*.

Comment: I think Bill Gates could figure this out... Anyway, you haven't defined what you mean by 'sub-sequence' very well. I think you mean something like 'sequence of numbers where each value is one larger than the previous value,' but you also seem to be dealing with a sequence of characters containing decimal representations of numbers.

Comment: Split the problem into smaller problems. Can you 1) interpret the string as sequences of numbers? If you can, can you then 2) find consecutive runs? And then 3) find the longest?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you are right, it is a consecutive run. The question needs clarification. It says subsequence but it seems OP means substring.

Comment: Sorry I reversal terms of stack by this question, i'm working now on algorithm and will post it here in minutes.

Comment: Now I edited code and my mention, now please check

Comment: Dear Bill, the correct spelling is **length**, not `lenght`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you actually meant *subsequence*, just guess the digit your sequence starts with and then run a linear scan. If you meant substring, it's even easier --- left as an exercise to OP.

The linear scan goes like this:

```
char next = <guessed digit>;
int len = 0;
char *ptr = <pointer to input string>;
while (*ptr) {
  if ((*ptr) == next) {
    next = next + 1;
    if (next > '9') next = '0';
    len++;
  }
  ptr++;
}
```

Now wrap that with a loop that sets  to all digits from '0' to '9' and you are done, pick the one that gives the longest length.

Comment: This is not going to work for sequences like `"401401403404405"` (401, 402, 403, 404, 405)

Comment: I think you are solving a different problem than me. I understood he is looking for the longest subsequence where digits are in sequence 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 9, and then wrap around.

Comment: I agree that this is a valid interpretation, too - the problem in the OP is definitely under-defined.

Answer (score 0):

simple idea: start point, end point and length of the sequence.

Run loop i

sequence will start whenever current number (at index i) less than next number 1 => start point set = i

it ends when condition above false => get end point  => get the length = end -start (make more variable called max to compare lengths) => result could be max, reset start point, end point = 0 again when end of sequence

Answer (score 0):

I made it myself:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
bool cons(int list[] , int iv) { bool ret=true; for (int a=0; a<=iv; a++) { if (list[a] != list[a+1]-1) ret=false; } return ret; }

void main() {
int str[10] = {12,13,15,16,17,18,20,21};
int longest=0;
int pos=0;
for (int lenght=1; lenght <= 9; lenght++) {
    int li[10];
    for (int seek=0; seek <= 9; seek++) {
        for (int kor=0; kor <= lenght-1; kor ++ ) {
            li[kor] = str[seek+kor];
        }
        if (cons(li , lenght-2)) {
            longest = lenght;
            pos=seek;
        } 
    }
}

for (int b=pos; b <= pos+longest-1; b++) cout << str[b] << " - "; cout << "it is the end!" << endl; getchar();


}
```